# UITableViewCell should stop Forwarding Touch Events to ScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i have a custom UITableViewCell with a DrawingView as a subview. if the user try to draw something on that view everytime the touch events are forwarded to the underlying ScrollView (UITableView) and than the view scrolls. How can i disable the forwarding from the touch/scroll-events to the scrollView, that the user can draw on the DrawingView?

Any idear's? I tests the exclusiveTouch property, methods like hitTest or touchBegan to captcher the events and stop the scrolling, but nothing helped. Thanks for helping!

Comment: If disabling scrolling is enough, try self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;

Comment: i don't want to disable scrolling, because the other cells aren't for drawing. If you drag this cell the scrollView should scroll..

Comment: A dirty trick would be disabling scrolling temporarily with the @EDUsta line as long as the user touches the DrawingView. You can catch the touchesBegan/touchesEnded events to enable/disable scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

The caveat here is that a 'drawing' motion could very easily be interpreted as a scrolling motion.

What you need to do is override pointInside on your cell.

Effectively:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point
          withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(drawingView.frame, point)) {
        // Use the point to do the drawing
        [drawingView drawAtPoint:point];
        // Disable scrolling for good measure
        self.tableView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
        return NO;
    }
    // Enable scrolling
    self.tableView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    return [super pointInside:point withEvent:event];
}
```

What this means is that as long as the user touches your cell inside the drawingView, scrolling won't happen.

If you're looking to scroll and draw at the same time from within the drawingView, that's going to be a lot kludgier to pull off.

See if this works. You may have to do some extra work like forwarding the point to your drawingView to draw something at the point.

Be careful that even if your finger is touching the same point, the pointInside method could be called multiple times so take care of duplicate events being called.